# Send a contact us form details to email in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a **Contact us** form page in my Flutter app and would like to send the details of the form (email of the user, name and the message) to my email address when the user hits the Send button. I don't want to launch the gmail app from phone for this. Are there any other ways to this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can.

You can use the [flutter_email_sender](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_email_sender) package or [flutter_mailer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mailer) package. Both of them are very similiar.

For example if you are using `flutter_email_sender` package,

```
final Email myFormEmail = Email(
  body: 'Email body', // This could be from the form field's value
  subject: 'Email subject', // Subject (maybe type of question, etc)
  recipients: ['example@example.com'], // This is receiver (maybe your email)
  cc: ['cc@example.com'],
  bcc: ['bcc@example.com'],
  attachmentPaths: ['/path/to/attachment.zip'],  // Attachments
  isHTML: false,
);
```

And then inside the 'SEND' button, add this kind of code:

```
await FlutterEmailSender.send(myFormEmail);
```

Comment: Thank you! Both call the same send method and launch the email apps. Is there any way to do this in the background?

Comment: @Peter Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Please check "mailer" package from flutter. It will use smtp to send email from background without opening userinterface app. It has gmail, yahoo mail, mailgun options to send email.

The Reference link :

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mailer